# Adding condition in Telerik Control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

There is a grid in which we've two columns

1. Email
2. IsOptin

The value of isOptin could be true or false

So we need to check if Email is isOptin then perform some functionality(which we will write in brackets after Title tag:- Title("here"))

So currently this

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Email)
               .Title();
```

is working like picking each email id and performing functionality. Now we need to create a scenario:-

**Pick email id and check whether it is Optin or not.**

kindly suggest what are the changes or addition need to be done.

Comment: I'm actually working on something similar. Are just looking to display different text based on the boolean variable?

Comment: Based on the boolean variable we will change the style of the Email id's filling in the grid column.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the ternary operator within the `ClientTemplate` of your bound column to perform a check of the `IsOptIn` field and display the appropriate field or text repsonse.

Sample below (updated):

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Email)
    .Title()
    .ClientTemplate("#: data.Email ##: data.IsOptin ? ' (Opt-In)' : '' #");
```

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks for the prompt reply. But it is not working. No error/exception appear on screen. Just upload all the emails...

Comment: Are you using client or server binding on your Kendo grids?

Comment: Could you provide your full code and controller action please?

Comment: I've amended the sample for you.  This should show example@domain.com (Opt-In) where IsOptIn is true.